# Updating main GUI Elements in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to update the main gui in a java swing application, so there is a runnable thread that keeps the main gui visible, but the problem is it is called in main, and main is a static function. I would like to say Element.SetTtext. But all calls that I want to update are not static. How can I update the lables,..etc in the Main GUI then?

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                new AGC().setVisible(true);
          // code to update labels here
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The only thing your main routine should be doing is SwingUtilities.invokeLater().  All of your GUI elements should be defined in the constructors of your GUI class(es).  The instance of the class that contains (not extends) the JFrame can be passed to whatever other GUI classes need the reference.  Read this article on how to construct a simple Swing GUI.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=38

Comment: Assuming the thread has access (a reference) to the Swing form, you can call public non-static methods of the form without passing through the static methods. Your update procedure can be defined in a public non-static method in the form

Comment: They are not in other classes. I just got an object from another class and I have it now in the Main GUI. It has properties that I want to display/update it in the main thread where should I put those gets/sets ?

Comment: @Barranka The only place is in the static main method which has Runnable thread. That place is static, and I can not put any code that needs to be updated because for example the gui elements are not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you think static means non-changeable. This is not true with Java. In Java objects and components that never change are characterized as **final**.

Keep your main simple and small and make your loops and changes in `doThings();`

Here is a Timer in order to update the text of the JLabel:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    public Foo() {
        jLabel1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        add(jPanel1);
        pack();
        // code to update whatever you like here
        doThings();
    }

    private void doThings() {
        // code to update whatever you like here
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                jLabel1.setText("foo " + (j++));
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, actionListener);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Foo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private int j = 0;
}
```

Comment: The main is static, hence everything that I want to run in its thread must be static " I think ".

Comment: That is true. In a static method you can only manipulate static variables. The reason for that is that static variables and methods exist even if you have not created an instance. They are called Class Variables and Class Methods.

Comment: yes, then how do I update the GUI elements like Lables inside the main gui class ? I want to update them frequently...

Comment: You can do this in your constructor. Or in any non-static method called by your constructor. Avoid putting the logic of your class in main.

Comment: Yes, and so does the main in your code. I have added you a Timer in the doThings method, which refreshes the JLabel forever. See here: docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html and all this stuff is written in books.

Answer (score 1):

little more clarity is required , when do u want to update the labels ? is it based on an event ?

You can always keep a global variable of the component you want to update and access it from the event handlers.

Can you please update your question with the code , so that it gives a better clarity ?

Comment: I would like for example in the Main GUI to have a timer that updates all the textlabels in the main thread. is it possible ? or use the runnable thread that is in the main gui to update the main gui textlabels ?